# Firebase Realtime Database Connection Data - Web

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, dom, firebase-realtime-database

I have to show data belonging to a user that logged in.

My database structure is as follows:

Users/Drivers/Uid/name,phone...
How can I show the data of a user that logged in by using JavaScript as a Text?

```
<a> Username </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this HTML:

```
<a id="username"> Username </a>
```

And this database structure:

```
Users
  Drivers
    Uid: { name: "Name", phone: "Phone number" }
```

Then you can display the name of the current user with:

```
var currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var userRef = firebase.database().ref("Users/Drivers").child(currentUser.uid);
userRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  document.getElementById("username").innerText = snapshot.val().name;
})
```

So this code does (line by line):

1. Determine the current user
2. Create a reference to that user's data in the database
3. Starts listening for that data, meaning it loads the current data, and then monitors for any changes
4. Puts the name of the user into the element.

Line 4 will be called immediately, with the current value of the user, and then every time that user data change.

Also see the Firebase documentation on [listening for values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events).

If the page can also be loaded when the user is not signed in (yet), you'll want to make sure to only run this code when the user *did* sign in. You can do this by using a so-called auth state change listener, which is called whenever the user's auth state changes:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    var userRef = firebase.database().ref("Users/Drivers").child(user.uid);
    userRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
      document.getElementById("username").innerText = snapshot.val().name;
    })
  }
});
```

See the Firebase documentation on [getting the current signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)..

Comment: I got an error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null

Comment: That means the user is not signed in. I added a sample for that. At this point I recommend that you spend some time in the Firebase documentation, and definitely take the [codelab for web developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/) as it covers all the code you are struggling with.